# How to get the buffer for an image in javascript uploaded to a form in html?

Tags: javascript, html

Code:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How can I get the buffer of the uploaded image in javascript?

Comment: Can you please detail in your question whether the image should be processed on the client (the browser) or on a server?

Answer (score 0):

You get the buffer of the image when you write it to memory so you would either need a node js server or PHP backend to retrieve the buffer.

**Using javascript**
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readfile-method/

**Using php**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php